# openshift node.js error after pushing new repo and start build

Tags: openshift

I just fixed few things on my website, I pushed new repository to github and clicked Start Build. 
New build pod throw event

```
    Failed Scheduling 
    0/133 nodes are available: 1 node(s) were not ready, 126 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 6 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

Comment: I assume this is for OpenShift Online?  If so, it will probably fix itself shortly as it appears the nodes you were assigned in the free tier needed rebalancing.  If you try again, it will probably work.

Comment: Have seen a report like this for ca cluster. Suggest you reach out via https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html and provide details.

Answer (score 0):

Openshift fixed it by its own. I just had to wait one day.